# How to reverse a chain of linked memory in a linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Right now, I'm trying to write a reverse method for a Doubly Linked List. It's not just one of the methods where you reverse from start to finish, but specifically a part of the list starting from one point and ending at a point after the start. The method takes in `ListNode` pointer references called `startPoint` and `endPoint`, and they should point at the new start and end of the chain in the linked memory. The `next` member of the `ListNode` before the start of the sequence (so `startPoint->prev`) should point at the new start, and the `prev` member of the `ListNode` after the end of the sequence (so `endPoint->next`) should point to the new end.

A key aspect I should point out is that we may **NOT** allocate any new `ListNodes`.

In my List.h file, I have a private class `ListNode`. I provided that along with the rest of my List class:

```
template <class T>
class List {
  private:
    class ListNode {
      public:
        ListNode();
        ListNode(const T & ndata);
        ListNode* next;
        ListNode* prev;
        const T data;
    };

  public:
    List();
    List(const List<T>& other);
    List<T>& operator=(const List<T>& rhs);
    int size() const;
    void print(ostream& os = std::cout) const;
    bool empty() const;
    ~List();
    void insertFront(const T& ndata);
    void insertBack(const T& ndata);
    void reverse();
    void tripleRotate();
    List<T> split(int splitPoint);

  private:
    ListNode* head_;
    ListNode* tail_;
    int length_;
    void _copy(const List<T>& other);
    void _destroy();

    /**
     * Helper function to reverse a sequence of linked memory inside a
     * List, starting at startPoint and ending at endPoint. You are
     * responsible for updating startPoint and endPoint to point to the
     * new starting and ending points of the rearranged sequence of
     * linked memory in question.
     *
     * @param startPoint A pointer reference to the first node in the
     *  sequence to be reversed.
     * @param endPoint A pointer reference to the last node in the
     *  sequence to be reversed.
     */
    void reverse(ListNode*& startPoint, ListNode*& endPoint);
};
```

In my List.hpp file, I have the reverse method itself. I am lost on how exactly to write it. Here's what I have so far (it obviously doesn't work):

```
template <typename T>
void List<T>::reverse(ListNode *& startPoint, ListNode *& endPoint) {
  if (startPoint == endPoint) {
    return;
  }
  //startPoint should point at the new start, endPoint should point at the new end.
  ListNode* current = startPoint;
  ListNode* before_start_point = startPoint->prev;
  ListNode* after_end_point = endPoint->next;
  while (current != after_end_point) {
    ListNode* temp = current->next;
    current->next = current->prev;
    current->prev = temp;
    if (temp == endPoint) {
      endPoint = startPoint;
      startPoint = current;
    }
    current = temp;
  }
}
```

The rest of the List.hpp file:

```
template <class T>
List<T>::List() { 
    head_ = NULL;
    tail_ = NULL;
    length_ = 0;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::_destroy() {
  ListNode* current = head_;
  while (current != NULL) {
    ListNode* temp = current->next;
    delete current;
    current = temp;
  }
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::insertFront(T const & ndata) {
  ListNode* newNode = new ListNode(ndata);
  //Case where there the list is empty
  if (head_ == NULL) {
    head_ = newNode;
    tail_ = newNode;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
  }
  else {
    newNode->next = head_;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    head_->prev = newNode;
    head_ = newNode;
  }
  length_++;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::insertBack(const T & ndata) {
  ListNode* newNode = new ListNode(ndata);
  if (tail_ == NULL) {
    head_ = newNode;
    tail_ = newNode;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
  }
  else {
    newNode->prev = tail_;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    tail_->next = newNode;
    tail_ = newNode;
  }
  length_++;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::ListNode* List<T>::split(ListNode* start, int splitPoint) {
  //There will be splitPoint number of nodes remaining in the current list
  ListNode* curr = start;
  if (splitPoint == 0) {
    return curr;
  }

  //Takes you to the start of the new list
  for (int i = 0; i < splitPoint && curr != NULL; i++) {
    curr = curr->next;
  }

  if (curr != NULL) {
      curr->prev->next = NULL;
      curr->prev = NULL;
  }

  //Return the head of the new sublist
  return curr;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::tripleRotate() {
  if (length_ < 3) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    int third_element_counter = 1;
    bool first_rotation = true;
    int divisible_by_three = length_ % 3;
    ListNode* current = head_;
    while (current != NULL) {
      if (third_element_counter != 3) {
        third_element_counter++;
      }
      else {
        ListNode* first = current->prev->prev;
        ListNode* temp_first_prev = first->prev;
        ListNode* second = current->prev;
        ListNode* temp_current = current;
        ListNode* temp_current_next = current->next; 
        second->prev = temp_first_prev;
        if (temp_first_prev != NULL) {
          temp_first_prev->next = second;
        }
        if (temp_current_next != NULL) {
          temp_current_next->prev = first;
        }
        current->next = first;
        first->next = temp_current_next;
        first->prev = temp_current;
        if (first_rotation) {
          head_ = second;
          first_rotation = false;
        }
        if (divisible_by_three == 0) {
          tail_ = first;
        }
        current = first;
        third_element_counter = 1;
      }
      current = current->next;
    }
  }
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::reverse() {
  reverse(head_, tail_);
}
```

Any sort of help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a reverse LinkedList in C++ from a given LinkedList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908193/create-a-reverse-linkedlist-in-c-from-a-given-linkedlist)

Comment: You haven't provided enough code. What is the `List` class?

Comment: @MysteriousUser Just edited my post. You should be able to see the List class now.

Comment: @HughJass24 can you please also provide the implementation of the `List` methods? So we can test it completely without having to implement them.

Comment: @MysteriousUser Just added the implementation. I have tested all the other functions beforehand and they all work. The reverse function does not work, however.

Comment: @HughJass24 You forgot to provide the `List::print()`, but I implemented it. I will edit my answer now, but my fix worked either way.

Comment: @HughJass24 See my edit. I also provided a link so you can see the program running: https://godbolt.org/z/nad7vT is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Given your code, I manually created a list of ten integers:

```
    List<int> my_list;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        my_list.insertBack(i);
    }
```

Then, I printed the list:

```
std::cout << "Before reverse:" << std::endl;
    my_list.print();
```

The output was:

```
Before reverse:
Node: 0
Node: 1
Node: 2
Node: 3
Node: 4
Node: 5
Node: 6
Node: 7
Node: 8
Node: 9
```

Then, I ran a slightly modified version of your reverse function:

```
template <typename T>
void List<T>::reverse(ListNode *& startPoint, ListNode *& endPoint) {
  if (startPoint == endPoint) {
    return;
  }

  //startPoint should point at the new start, endPoint should point at the new end.
  ListNode* current = startPoint;
  ListNode* before_start_point = startPoint->prev;
  ListNode* after_end_point = endPoint->next;
  while (current != after_end_point) {
    std::cout << "Working with current node " << current->data << std::endl;
    ListNode* temp = current->next;
    std::cout << "Temp is " << (temp ? temp->data : 0) << std::endl;
    current->next = current->prev;
    std::cout << current->data << "'s new next is now " << (current->next ? current->next->data : 0) << std::endl;
    current->prev = temp;
    std::cout << current->data << "'s new prev is now " << (current->prev ? current->prev->data : 0) << std::endl;

    if (temp == endPoint) {
      endPoint = startPoint;
      startPoint = temp;
    }
    current = temp;
  }
}
```

And printed again:

```
    std::cout << "After reverse:" << std::endl;
    my_list.print();
```

The output was:

```
After reverse:
Node: 9
Node: 8
Node: 7
Node: 6
Node: 5
Node: 4
Node: 3
Node: 2
Node: 1
Node: 0
```

So it seems the only problem was in the `if` block at the end of the `while` loop, where you were assigning `startPoint = current` when instead it should be either `startPoint = endPoint` or `startPoint = temp` (because when the `if` is true, `temp` is equal to `endPoint`).

This is the complete code (also available in https://godbolt.org/z/nad7vT):

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class List {
  private:
    class ListNode {
      public:
        ListNode();
        ListNode(const T & ndata) : data{ndata} {};
        ListNode* next;
        ListNode* prev;
        const T data;
    };

  public:
    List();
    List(const List<T>& other);
    List<T>& operator=(const List<T>& rhs);
    int size() const;
    void print(std::ostream& os = std::cout) const;
    bool empty() const;
    ~List() {};
    void insertFront(const T& ndata);
    void insertBack(const T& ndata);
    void reverse();
    void reverseNth(int n);
    void tripleRotate();
    List<T> split(int splitPoint);

  private:
    ListNode* head_;
    ListNode* tail_;
    int length_;
    void _copy(const List<T>& other);
    void _destroy();

    /**
     * Helper function to reverse a sequence of linked memory inside a
     * List, starting at startPoint and ending at endPoint. You are
     * responsible for updating startPoint and endPoint to point to the
     * new starting and ending points of the rearranged sequence of
     * linked memory in question.
     *
     * @param startPoint A pointer reference to the first node in the
     *  sequence to be reversed.
     * @param endPoint A pointer reference to the last node in the
     *  sequence to be reversed.
     */
    void reverse(ListNode*& startPoint, ListNode*& endPoint);
};

template <typename T>
void List<T>::reverse(ListNode *& startPoint, ListNode *& endPoint) {
  if (startPoint == endPoint) {
    return;
  }

  //startPoint should point at the new start, endPoint should point at the new end.
  ListNode* current = startPoint;
  ListNode* before_start_point = startPoint->prev;
  ListNode* after_end_point = endPoint->next;
  while (current != after_end_point) {
    std::cout << "Working with current node " << current->data << std::endl;
    ListNode* temp = current->next;
    std::cout << "Temp is " << (temp ? temp->data : 0) << std::endl;
    current->next = current->prev;
    std::cout << current->data << "'s new next is now " << (current->next ? current->next->data : 0) << std::endl;
    current->prev = temp;
    std::cout << current->data << "'s new prev is now " << (current->prev ? current->prev->data : 0) << std::endl;

    if (temp == endPoint) {
      endPoint = startPoint;
      startPoint = temp;
    }
    current = temp;
  }
}

template <class T>
List<T>::List() { 
    head_ = NULL;
    tail_ = NULL;
    length_ = 0;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::_destroy() {
  ListNode* current = head_;
  while (current != NULL) {
    ListNode* temp = current->next;
    delete current;
    current = temp;
  }
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::insertFront(T const & ndata) {
  ListNode* newNode = new ListNode(ndata);
  //Case where there the list is empty
  if (head_ == NULL) {
    head_ = newNode;
    tail_ = newNode;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
  }
  else {
    newNode->next = head_;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    head_->prev = newNode;
    head_ = newNode;
  }
  length_++;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::insertBack(const T & ndata) {
  ListNode* newNode = new ListNode(ndata);
  if (tail_ == NULL) {
    head_ = newNode;
    tail_ = newNode;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
  }
  else {
    newNode->prev = tail_;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    tail_->next = newNode;
    tail_ = newNode;
  }
  length_++;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::print(std::ostream& os) const {
    for(const ListNode *it = head_; it != nullptr; it = it->next) {
        os << "Node: " << it->data << std::endl;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::reverse() {
  reverse(head_, tail_);
}

int main() {

    List<int> my_list;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        my_list.insertBack(i);
    }

    std::cout << "Before reverse:" << std::endl;
    my_list.print();
      
    my_list.reverse();

    std::cout << "After reverse:" << std::endl;
    my_list.print();

    
    return 0;
}
```